# Bootstrap tab not calling JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have Tried 2,3 solution but none worked for me ...

I have 3 Maps which I want to show in Tabs .Only 1st one appears .On Tab Change I Tried call the jQuery function first ..But the function is not even firing .

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Google Maps API v3 : KML Layer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //activaTab('overview'); --1.this is not working 
        });

      //2.this is not working 
        //$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        //      alert('not ok');
        //});

      //3.not working    

        //$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
          //  alert(target);
            //var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab

        //});

        4.Not working
        //function activaTab(tab) {
        //    alert(tab);
        //    $('.tab-pane a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');

        //};

        function display_kmlmap() {
            var map_options = {};

            //--Nation--
            var mapNation = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_nation"), map_options);
            var kmlUrlNation = 'http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.7/kmz/HTI_adm0.kmz';
            var kmlOptionsNation = { map: mapNation };
            kmlLayerNation = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrlNation, kmlOptionsNation);
            $("#map_nation").css("width", 400).css("height", 400);



            //--District--
            var mapDistrict = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_department"), map_options);
            var kmlUrlDistrict = 'http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.7/kmz/HTI_adm2.kmz';
            var kmlOptionsDistrict = { map: mapDistrict };
            kmlLayerDistrict = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrlDistrict, kmlOptionsDistrict);
            $("#map_department").css("width", 400).css("height", 400);


            //--Commune--
            var mapCommune = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_Commune"), map_options);
            var kmlUrlCommune = 'http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.7/kmz/HTI_adm3.kmz';
            var kmlOptionsCommune = { map: mapCommune };
            kmlLayerCommune = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrlCommune, kmlOptionsCommune);
            $("#map_Commune").css("width", 400).css("height", 400);




        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="display_kmlmap()">

    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Nation View</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#photos" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Department View</a>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#Commune" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Commune View</a>

            </li>
        </ul>




        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">
                <div id='map_nation'></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="photos">
                <div id='map_department'>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="Commune">
                <div id='map_Commune'>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; float: left">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried 3 solution , I mentioned in Code .. but none of them are working ...i am not getting any clue

What Am I missing ??

Comment: The problem is probably in fact the the other `div` elements are hidden when the second and third map is created

Comment: Tahts why I want to assign a function which will recreate the map when tab selected ...How can i achieve it ?